# Linewise inclusive delete up to a pattern

Tags: vim

Suppose you want to delete a **C** function from its name up to and *including* the line with the closing curly:

```
int main (void)   /* Cursor on this line. */
{
   while (...) {
      ...
   }
}
```

I have tried `d/^}<CR>` but this does not delete the line with the closing curly. How can I have an *inclusive find pattern* delete? I must be missing something simple.

**Edit** You can assume the function's closing curly is at the start of a line and other curlies are never.

Comment: Well, then what about `d/^}<CR>dd` :)

Comment: Then I can't paste the function with just `p`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did a quick search and found the *offset* syntax of the `/` operator [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/).

```
d/^}/0
```

did the trick for me. It means "find the matching pattern, then select to the end of the 0th line after it" (i.e. the end of the line it is found on)

Answer (score 5):

Use `V][d`.

It means:

- **V**: Enter in Visual Mode.
- **][**: Move until next `}`
- **d**: Delete all visual selection.

Answer (score 3):

Your command won't work on functions that have nested braces.  I would delete to the first '{' with `0d]]`, followed by `daB` to delete the block.

Details for new vimmers: The `'0'` in the first command makes sure you're at the start of the line before editing the `d` command.  `']]'` is a motion that gets you to the next block, and `'aB'` is a selecting motion that selects the whole block, including nested blocks.  So `0d]]daB` means delete from the start of the line to the next block, then delete the block.

Comment: Well, with my coding style, i.e. indenting with each brace level, it does work, since I anchor the search with `^}`.

Comment: @Jens I see.  But perhaps its best to use something reusable, e.g. if you want to delete an if statement and it's following block.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `jVaBokd`

`j` - move down a line

`VaB` - visual line select on outer block

`o` - move to the opposite end of the visual selection

`k` - move up a line

`d` - delete selection